# explicit instantiation of a templated function in the templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The header file of the class is as follows:

```
 enum class My_Type {
     type1,
     type2
 };

 template <int dim>
 class My_Class {
 public:
     My_Class() {};

     template <My_Type p_type>
     void
     func();
 }
```

cpp file:

```
template <int dim>
template <My_Type p_type>
void
My_Class<dim>::func() {
     if (p_type==My_Type::type1) {
         ...
     } else {
         ...
     }
     ....
}
```

the call is as follows:

```
My_Class<2> my_obj;
my_obj.template func<My_Type::type1>();
```

Everything compiles fine but does not link:

```
'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64'
```

This is because the part of the code is inside a library. Thus I need to explicitly instantiate.

For the class this is obvious:

```
 template class My_Class<2>;
```

The question is, how do I instantiate the templated function in such a case? Any tricks or workarounds?

p/s/ as you see from `enum`, I use C++11 if that matters.

p/p/s/ i looked through couple of links, but not sure if I saw the solution.

Comment: It's possible to do it this way if you know the complete finite set of all useful instantiations, but it's usually easier to just put all template definitions in header files.  (And having an `int` parameter doesn't sound like it should have just a few possible instantiations.)

Comment: @aschepler thanks for the advice. if things grow big, i'll move definitions to header. So far i have only 4 variants altogether for both templated arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny enough, by trial-and-error I deduced the correct syntax:

```
template class MyClass<2>;
template void MyClass<2>::func< My_Type::type1>();
template void MyClass<2>::func< My_Type::type2>();
```